# Sometimes when a user sends me an image (screenshot) in Gmail it doesn't display properly

Tags: gmail, images

Sometimes when a customer sends me an email with an attached screenshot it doesn't display properly in my inbox. I see this sort of text instead of the image:

[image: screenshot]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or they are doing wrong when pasting the image into the email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not yours, it's the sender's fault.
They probably drag&dropped image in their mail compose  window and the worst  part is that their email provider don't support such feature or they did it incorrectly.

Ask them to attach the image to the mail or if you can't do so you  can still open the image using it's base64 encoding (the long series of alphabets and numbers). Copy the long text inside the quotes after `src` and paste it into the browser's addressbar and hit enter, if done correctly you will see the image. But it's difficult to work with such long text so you better ask them to upload the image somewhere and share it with you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a faulty link to me, like they tried pasting the screenshot directly into the mail. You can ask them to upload the picture to a site like imgur.com or photobucket.com and mail the link, or you can have a Google Drive folder where they can store pictures but not read/download pictures. Also make sure you're accepting images from your client in gmail.

Comment: but it works when I paste directly into an email?

Comment: Might be different between different operating systems, local settings etc. I do not know an answer to this question since it can depend on many varying factors.

Comment: And it isn't a link it is someone pasting a screenshot into an email.

Comment: It's not a hyperlink, but an image link (<img src=....). That's the fault link I was referring to, not a clickable URL.